Error bars on PGFPlot are showing up as boxes
I'm plotting a graph with error bars in both directions. I used the examples from the manual:
% Preamble: \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.18}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+ [
    error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,y explicit,
        x dir=both,x explicit,
] coordinates {
    (0,0)     +- (0.5,0.1)
    (0.1,0.1) +- (0.05,0.2)
    (0.2,0.2) +- (0,0.05)
    (0.5,0.5) +- (0.1,0.2)
    (1,1)     +- (0.3,0.1)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

as I want the graph to look like this

Here is my code
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid=both,
xlabel={Test data},
ylabel={Untrained mean predictions},
xmin=6.0E+05, xmax=8.0E+05,
ymin=6.0E+05, ymax=8.0E+05,
xtick={6.0E+05, 6.5E+05, 7.0E+05, 7.5E+05, 8.0E+05},
ytick={6.0E+05, 6.5E+05, 7.0E+05, 7.5E+05, 8.0E+05}]


\addplot+[dashed, color=black, mark=none]
coordinates {
(   6.0E+05 ,   6.0E+05 )
(   8.0E+05 ,   8.0E+05 )
};

\addplot+[error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit, x dir=both, x explicit]
coordinates {
(6.0908E+05,6.0910E+05)+-(2.6465E+03,3.1317E+03)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

but this is what I'm getting.

There is a rectangle where the error bars are. How do I get rid of this and just have standard error bars?
Thanks,
Emma

Your error bars are smaller than the mark (try with E+04 instead of E+03 for the uncertainty).

Thank for your response. Yes I realised that it's the mark and nothing to do with the error bars. I have removed the markers, and I can now see the error bars. Do you know if it's possible to change the length of the error bar markers i.e. the ticks at the end of the error bars? They are quite wide and making the point look like unfilled boxes. I have tried using 'error mark options' but this doesn't seem to work

You can try error bars/error mark.
